# How to hyperlink to file in KingsoftOffice?

Tags: file-system, hyperlinks

I have an Excel spreadsheet created in Windows and open in Kingsoft Office. I would like to be able to create a hyperlink to specific files on the tablet itself.  For example, I want to be able to link to `/Root/sdcard/Cool Example Folder/12345.pdf`.  How would I go about doing this?

If Kingsoft Office won't do this, is there an Android app that will let me do this?

Samsung Galaxy Tab, Android OS `4.0.4`.