# Hyperlinks to files in the Android 10 file system

Tags: file-system, android-10, hyperlinks

I seem to have tripped over a rarely attempted task in relation to links to files on the Android file system. There is one other question about this from 2013 and it was never answered ([How to hyperlink to file in KingsoftOffice?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39554/how-to-hyperlink-to-file-in-kingsoftoffice)).

I want to create a link to a file in the Android file system (any file e.g. a PDF) within a document (e.g. for Excel or Word).

I have my reasons which can be explained later if there is a solution.

In the absence of a means to create such links in the apps, I obtained the pathname for a PDF on my Android phone and copied it to a Word-App doc on OneDrive. On my PC, I added a hyperlink to the doc linking to the Android pathname. Back on the mobile, with the updated doc open and the link visible, tapping the link resulted in the message -:

*"Can't open. There's no web browser installed for this user profile, so the page couldn't be opened"*

It seems the link is treated as an external link requiring a browser when Android needs to know that the PDF has an app it can use. Or it needs to open the default browser (Chrome) where the browser needs a PDF viewer extension, perhaps.

Otherwise, I don't know Android well enough to know where to go from here.

10/04/2023
Update

An example of the pathname is -:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/xxx.pdf
```

I have found that prepending "file://", the added text just disappears on 'save' leaving the above pathname unaltered.

On changing to `http://storage/emulated/0/Download/xxx.pdf` the "http:/" remains in place and the error message changes to "Cannot display PDF (filename.PDF cannot be opened)"

I deduce from this that the system recognises the hyperlink to the file and can extract and "understand" the filename but possibly can't find it or does not have permission to display it.

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a path you tried? Note that if you connect your phone to a PC via USB the phone shows some sort of virtual file-system to the PC so every path you generate that way is not-existent as it is only valid for the USB connection (thus the MTP protocol).

Comment: Possibly related: [How can you get a local filesystem link of an offline-accessible PDF file in Dropbox?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124689/44325). I believe the hyperlink should start with the `file://` protocol.

Comment: @RayButterworth Thanks for those details. So, if I use a comment as reason to update my question, and answers should not be given in Comments, how can anyone answer my question? On this page I see an "Answer your Question" button which seems odd at first sight - it's implying that a user can only answer their own question. On other systems there is a "Reply" button, but not here.

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm not quite sure whether I should be answering your comment here but I have no other way of replying to you - The file:// prefix is removed from the link as soon as I add it. If I prefix with "http://" the message changes to "Cannot display PDF (filename.PDF cannot be opened)" which implies it at least recognises the filename part of the pathname. It's disconcerting that I used the file app to get the file path and yet it can't be found.

Comment: `http://` belongs to the HTTP protocol which means you need an HTTPS server which is not existent on Android. Thus http:// is totally wrong if you are trying to access a local file.

Comment: @theHeatingEngineer sees only an "Answer your own question".  Correct, but everyone else sees an "Answer the question". You get the different wording so that you will be reminded that it's actually your own question you are about to answer (some of us might occasionally forget that :-).